# Convert a rigid transformation so that the rotation center is not the origin

Tags: python, algorithm, image-processing, computer-vision

Given a rotation matrix `R`, what is the equivalent transformation so that some point `c` (the new rotation center) is unchanged under the transformation `y = R * c`, i.e., change `R` so that the rotation center is at `c` rather than the origin. One limitation is that I cannot act on the actual vector to be used, only edit the original transformation (this is because that part is buried in an external library and I cannot change it).

I have something that works but it violates the above limitation:

```py
import numpy as np

# R is a given rotation matrix, v is an arbitrary vector and cen is the desired center

theta = np.pi / 2
cen = np.array([0.5, 0.5])
v = np.array([0, 0])
R = Rot(theta) # ordinary rotation matrix

y = R @ (v - center ) + cen 

# y = [0, 1] which is the expected result since we have a right angle triangle 
# with vertices at (0, 0) (0.5, 0.5) and (0, 1)
```

I also tried implementing a calculation similar to [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#getrotationmatrix2d) but the result I'm getting is not correct

How can I achive the same result but keeping the form `y = R*v` (or using a rigid transform `y = R*v + t`) but not changing `v` like I did?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While writing the question I came upon the (obvious) solution which is just expanding the solution I wrote before and rearranging. In case someone needs this as well the new transformations should be:

`y = R_new*v + t_new`

where `R_new = R`, `t_new = (I - R)*cen` and `I` is the identity.

Comment: If use homogeneous coordinates, then transformation matrix is T*R*(invT).